# Calling function when useState s called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Parent Component

```
const TopPage = (props) =>{
    const [fileUrl, setFileUrl ] = useState("");
    const onSetFileUrl = (data) =>{
        setFileUrl(data);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <ImagePreview fileUrl={fileUrl}></ImagePreview>
        </div>
    );    
}
```

Child Component

```
import React from 'react'
const ImagePreview = (props) =>{
    const layer = null;
    const onImageChange = () =>{
        var layer = document.getElementById('layer');
        var ctx = layer.getContext('2d');
        console.log("image is changed");
        const chara = new Image();
        chara.src = props.fileUrl;
        chara.onload = () => {
            ctx.drawImage(chara, 0, 0);          
        };
    }
    return (<div>Image Preview:{props.fileUrl}
   <canvas id="layer" style={{width: 100, height: 100,backgroundColor:"yellow"}} />
    </div>);
};

export default ImagePreview;
```

Parent Component gives the `fileUrl` to Child Component.

When data changed, `fileUrl` is given to Child Component via `props`.

However, at the same time I want to draw this in canvas.

So I need to call `onImageChange()` of Child Component when `fileUrl` is changed.

How can I do this ?

Comment: `useEffect` and a ref to your canvas.

Comment: Thank you I tried to use `useEffect` and problem issolved.